# How to Create a Shared DataSet in SSRS using BIDS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm using BIDS, or Visual Studio 2008. In Solution Explorer, under my project I have a "folder" for Shared Data Sources and a "folder" for Reports.
I've seen posts and screenshots all over that refer to and show a Shared Datasets "folder" too.
How do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please SSRS version you are running ? I have SSRS Version 10.50.2500.0, which have "Shared datasets" folder.

so my suggetion to update SSRS to following version.

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 10.50.2500.0

Comment: In my Visual Studio I got this: Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 10.0.1600.22. Pardon my ignorance... do I have to upgrade server, client or both?

Comment: I would start with clent. but i think you have to do both.

Comment: Hi Hiten004 - I uninstalled and installed again, and now I do see the Shared datasets folder. But at runtime it tells me that RSvces doesn't support it. So it's also the server's version. That's beyond my "power" here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you have an old version of SSRS on the server.
[SSRS Shared Datasets not supported in SQL Server 2008 R2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/4ccbdfbf-d2f1-4808-9477-b86866fff2d1)